# Need help removing Microsoft account and then adding it back

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, user

I recently got my laptop back from the repair man after the drive went out and I lost all my things. When he set up the new drive, he created a user to log in with, which had the name “User”. I got on and I logged in with my Microsoft account which paired the Microsoft account with the account. The main problem comes to my preference of having the name of my user folder “jack,” but it is now stuck as “User.” I then tried to change it by changing ProfileImagePath and changing my username in netplwiz. I restarted my computer and it said I cannot log in. I then changed everything back and could log in, but my User files were deleted, my settings were messed up, and my desktop was all disorganized. I would love if I could start fresh and create a new user that is solely my Microsoft account. Right now I can’t log in with just my Microsoft account since I’m already logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new enough back to you that you should make a new account.

If there is anything in "User", back it up to a USB Key. You said you lost all your things so likely not much there.

Now make a new Local Account  (say Jack_Admin) and member of Administrators.

Log into Jack_Admin and delete "User" and the "User" Profile (Advanced System Settings, Advanced Tab).

I suggest restarting now and logging back in as Jack_Admin.

Make a new Microsoft User called (I think) Jack. Use your email address and the first 4 characters will be your profile name (Windows Explorer, USERS).

This is the way I suggest to you because the situation is new, and this allows you to start fresh the way you want.

Good Luck with this.

Comment: Hey man thank you very much this saved me so much time and research. I must say that user management on Linux is much easier, but I’m a Windows user at heart. Anyways thanks again!

Comment: It’s unnecessary to delete the Windows user, just disconnecting the account from the Microsoft account, will prompt the user to provide a new name for the profile.  Once that is done the author can connect the same local account they are currently using to the same Microsoft

Comment: I agree with you but since all is new, the way I described also works.

Comment: It’s just an ineffective and unnecessary method but since the author accepted I won’t bother complaining about it further